# how to display two column values without their null values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two columns let's say A and B , both columns contains some null values.

I want to display both column values excluding their null values.

Any suggestion or help would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you should some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `Where A IS NOT NULL` to your query to get rid of all of the null values in column A. You will need to modify this a bit to work with what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A, B FROM MYTABLE WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL
```

Feel free to comment in case you need few more logic in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNULL with column name, to replace Empty value if column contains NULL

<kbd>[SAMPLE SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a114/8)</kbd>

```
SELECT ISNULL(A,'') A, ISNULL(B,'') B
From TableName
```

If you dont want to show null records then Use in Where clause IS NULL NULL

```
SELECT A,B
From TableName
Where A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want results with no null values then use

`select a, b from your_table where a is not null and b is not null`

If you want results which can have one column null but not both

`select a, b from your_table where a is not null or b is not null`